# Fetch api post call returning 403 forbidden error in React js but the same URL working in postman

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Below code is not working and returning 403 forbidden but the same url giving the correct response postman tool.

```
fetch('https://example.com/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
 body:JSON.stringify(sampledata),
}).then(result => console.log('success====:', result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error============:', error));
```

Comment: what result do you get back in postman?

Comment: Success response in a json format with status 200

Comment: how are you running the code? Do you load the file from a local file or do you retrieve it from an http server?

Comment: @ManuRamV did you find its solution?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add **credentials: 'include'** to your request.

```
fetch('https://example.com/', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
      body: JSON.stringify(sampledata),

      }).then(result => console.log('success====:', result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error============:', error));
```

Comment: Works like a charm, my problem was really due to the credentials include

Answer (score 4):

Please read this article [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) , And change your API "Content-Type" to "text/plain". It will work (both fetch and axios)

```js
fetch('https://example.com/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', },
 body:JSON.stringify(sampledata),
}).then(result => console.log('success====:', result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error============:', error));
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably CORS problem. Regular web pages can send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions like postman aren't. You have to configure CORS on your backend.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Postman doesn't need to abide by `access-control-allow-origin` headers.  Browser vendors look for this header from host server.  If the server contains `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN: "*"` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"` this would then tell the browser that this resource has given permission to be accessed.